# Add site collection level application catalog

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I am using below PnP PowerShell command to add site collection level application catalog and giving me an Unauthorized error. I currently have owner access to the site.

**PowerShell**

```
$siteUrl = "https://site/"
Connect-PnPOnline $siteUrl

$site = Get-PnPSite

Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site $site
```

**ERROR**

> Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog : The remote server returned an error:
>   (401) Unauthorized. At line:6 char:1
>   + Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site $site
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Admin.AddSiteCollectionAppCatalog

Does 'Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog' command require more access or is this access enough for this command.

**EDIT**

Because I was getting this error I tried the same on Developer Tanet where I am an admin on the tenant which give me below error.

> Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog : Cannot invoke method or retrieve
>   property from null object. Object returned by the following  call
>   stack is null. "TenantAppCatalog RootWeb GetSiteByUrl new
>   Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant() " At
>   C:\Ravi\SPO\PowerShell\Add-SiteCollectionLevelAppCatalog.ps1:8 char:1
>   + Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site $site
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog], ServerException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Admin.AddSiteCollectionAppCatalog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You need SharePoint tenant admin access to enable Site collection app catalog. It is assumed that the we already have a tenant app catalog. If its not present, you need to create that first and then run the PS to add SCA.

2) `Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog` commandlet accepts the parameter `Site` which can be a string or Site object .

So, you can also use the command as below:

```
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site 
"https://your-tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/testSiteCollection"
```

References -

[Using Site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog)

[Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/blob/master/sharepoint/sharepoint-ps/sharepoint-pnp/Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog.md)

Comment: You are partially correct. 1) Correct on this. I was also facing some other error on my development tenant. The reason for the error was, in development tenant I did not have Tenant Level Application Catalog and because of that, I could not create Site Collection Level Application Catalog. 2) Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog can have site object as a parameter. If you look at the example on the link that you shared uses site object and not the url.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati - thanks, corrected.  Could please mark it as answer if it helped you ?